# The Residue Of $\int_{\gamma}\frac{cosz}{z^5}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

$$\int_{|z|=1}\frac{cosz}{z^5}dz$$

$$\frac{cosz}{z^5}=\frac{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nz^{2n}}{2n!}}{z^5}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nz^{2n}}{2n!\cdot z^5}=\frac{1}{z^5}-\frac{1}{2z^3}+\frac{1}{4!z}-\frac{z}{6!}+\frac{z^3}{8!}$$

How do I find $c_{-1}$?

Comment: Look at the $n=2$ term of your sum.

Comment: "How do I find $c_{-1}$?" By looking at the line above the line where you are asking this.

Comment: BTW, you are asking for the residue of a **function**, not of an integral...

Comment: Sorry, the correct question is what is $c_{-1}$

Comment: And the answer is the same: look one line above. Or, would you be missing a definition of what a residue is?

Comment: I know that I need to take the element before the first negative power

Comment: And which term in your power series is the first negative power?

Comment: $\frac{1}{z^5}=z^{-5}$

Comment: No, that's the fifth.

Comment: Coefficient of $\frac 1z$ is $c_{-1}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_{|z|=1}\frac{cosz}{z^5}dz  = 2i\pi f^{(4)}(0)/4! =2i\pi/4! $$
where $f(z) =  \cos (z)$
See here 
[Calculation of $\oint_{\vert z\vert=1}\frac{e^{z^2+\sin(z)}}{4(z-2)^2e^{\cos(z)}}dz$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2396641/calculation-of-oint-vert-z-vert-1-fracez2-sinz4z-22e-cosz/2396703#2396703).